# Proving a function is either surjective or injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f : (1, 3) → \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 − 4x + 3}$$

for all $x$ such that $1 < x < 3$.

Determine whether or not this function is injective and whether or not it is surjective. Justify your answers.

---

I am unsure in regards to proving either injective or surjective.

I let $f(x) = y$. And got two values for $x$

- $x = \frac{1-3y}{y}$
- $x = \frac{1-3y}{y} - 4$

Then I subbed these in two separate cases for the value $x$.

Answer (score 2):

**For injectivity:**

Since $f(x)=\dfrac1{x^2-4x+3}=\dfrac1{(x-2)^2-1}$ it follows that $2-t$ and $2+t$ have the same image under $f$, namely, $$f(\color{blue}{2-t})=\frac1{(\color{blue}{2-t}-2)^2-1}=\frac1{(-t)^2-1}=\frac1{t^2-1}=\frac1{(\color{blue}{2+t}-2)^2-1}=f(\color{blue}{2+t})$$
So $f$ is not injective in the interval $(1,3)$, you can convence yourself of this fact trying with, let's say $x_1=1.5$ and $x_2=2.5$.

**For surjectivity:**

Observe that $-1\le(x-2)^2-1 < 0$ for all $x\in(1,3)$, so there is not $x$ in $(1,3)$ such that give us $f(x)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, in proving injectivity and surjectivity, I like to do the following:

- **Injectivity:** Consider two different elements of your function domain, $a,b \in (1,3)$ with $a \neq b$. Find their values under $f$ and determine whether it is at all possible for them to be equal. If $a \neq b$ for **any** values imply $f(a) = f(b)$, then the function is not injective. This is sort of analogous to a "horizontal line test" if you have a function on a finite interval: if there exists a horizontal line through two different points on the graph of a function (think of $g(x) = x^2$), then it's not injective.
- **Surjectivity:** Try to find elements of the codomain that are never mapped to by the function, and verify why. For most functions you'll likely contend with in your coursework, these will be glaringly obvious reasons. If you can't find such elements that have no pre-image, try finding the inverse function and justifying that every element in the codomain can't have an image.

It's heuristic and the end method you use for each basically depends on what you're dealing with.

---

**Some hints:**

For injectivity, looking at a graph of a function can often be useful in cases like these where it's defined over an interval. Look one up, try to see if there are any useful values you could use. (The function is not injective, for the record - so find some $a \neq b$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. Simply demonstrating that statement for a specific $a,b$ is enough to disprove injectivity.

For surjectivity, graphs can also be helpful. Your function is also not surjective. Thus, assert that there exists some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x \in (1,3)$, $x$ cannot map to $y$.

For the latter, it'll also be helpful to note that the function can have its denominator factored:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - 4x + 3} = \frac{1}{(x-1)(x-3)}$$

Notice what happens for $1 < x < 3$, $(x-1) < 0$ and $(x-3)>0$, i.e. the denominator is always negative, and thus $f(x)$ is always negative over this domain. Using that, show that any specific positive real number cannot be mapped by $f$ is sufficient to show it's not surjective - it only takes one counterexample.